# Java wait notify with shared integer object

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 10 in sequence using a shared integer object across multiple threads. When using the shared object as AtomicInteger, the program works correctly, but when using normal Integer objects, the program throws an exception and I don't know why this is happening.

Program with AtomicInteger

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;  

public class ThreadingProblem {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    AtomicInteger sharedInt = new AtomicInteger(0);  
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadingPrintingTask(sharedInt), "PrinterThread");  
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadingIncrementingTask(sharedInt), "IncrementerThread");  
    t1.start();  
    t2.start();  
  }  
}  

class ThreadingPrintingTask implements Runnable {    

  private AtomicInteger sharedObject;  

  public ThreadingPrintingTask(AtomicInteger sharedObject) {  
    this.sharedObject = sharedObject;  
  }  

  @Override  
  public void run() {  
    try {  
      synchronized (sharedObject) {  
        while (true) {  
          sharedObject.wait();  
          System.out.println("Shared object value is: " + sharedObject);  
          sharedObject.notify();  
        }  
      }  
    }  
    catch (InterruptedException e) {  
    }  

  }  
}  

class ThreadingIncrementingTask implements Runnable {  

  private AtomicInteger sharedObject;  

  public ThreadingIncrementingTask(AtomicInteger sharedObject) {  
    this.sharedObject = sharedObject;  
  }  

  @Override  
  public void run() {  
    synchronized (sharedObject) {  
      while (this.sharedObject.get() < 10) {  
        this.sharedObject.incrementAndGet();  
        this.sharedObject.notify();  
        try {  
          this.sharedObject.wait();  
        }  
        catch (InterruptedException e) {  
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
          e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Output

```
Shared object value is: 1
Shared object value is: 2
Shared object value is: 3
Shared object value is: 4
Shared object value is: 5
Shared object value is: 6
Shared object value is: 7
Shared object value is: 8
Shared object value is: 9
Shared object value is: 10
```

Program with normal Integer object

```
public class ThreadingProblem {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer sharedInt = new Integer(0);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadingPrintingTask(sharedInt), "PrinterThread");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadingIncrementingTask(sharedInt), "IncrementerThread");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}

class ThreadingPrintingTask implements Runnable {

  private Integer sharedObject;

  public ThreadingPrintingTask(Integer sharedObject) {
    this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      synchronized (sharedObject) {
        while (true) {
          sharedObject.wait();
          System.out.println("Shared object value is: " + sharedObject);
          sharedObject.notify();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

  }
}

class ThreadingIncrementingTask implements Runnable {

  private Integer sharedObject;

  public ThreadingIncrementingTask(Integer sharedObject) {
    this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized (sharedObject) {
      while (this.sharedObject < 10) {
        this.sharedObject++;
        this.sharedObject.notify();
        try {
          this.sharedObject.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "IncrementerThread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.itiviti.apps.catalys.shared.mock.ThreadingIncrementingTask.run(ThreadingProblem.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this.sharedObject++;` does not do what you assumed it would do.

Since `Integer` is immutable, it can't change the existing shared object. What this operation does instead is unbox the value into an `int`, increment it, then box it back into a different `Integer` instance.

So your code is (almost*) equivalent to the following:

```
int temp = this.sharedObject.intValue();
temp = temp + 1;
this.sharedObject = new Integer(temp);
```

As at this point your object is no longer the same instance, your `synchronized` blocks won't line up with the `wait()`/`notify()` calls.

Note that this has got nothing to do with the atomicity of `AtomicInteger`, it's simply to do with how the `++` operator works on an `Integer`.

**In reality you might get a cached instance instead of `new Integer()`, but it will still be a different instance, as it represents a different `int` value.*